# Is XAMPP limiting the amount of videos that can be played simultaneously on a website?

Tags: html, video, xampp, html5-video

I have a problem with html video tag playback. I have 7 videos on a webpage like this:

```
<video autoplay preload loop muted style="width:630px">
    <source src="videotest/vid2.mp4">
</video>
```

When I run it from file explorer (double click index.html) all the 7 videos loads at the same time and starts to play right away.

But then when I try to run the same trough local server XAMPP (localhost/videotest), only 6 videos will load at the start and the last video will start many seconds later.

How could I get all the videos load at the same time trough XAMPP, even if they would lag/stutter?

I have tried to config my php.ini, but with no success. These are the settings I have changed in php.ini:

1. max_execution_time=90
2. max_input_time=60
3. memory_limit=1024M
4. post_max_size=1024M
5. upload_max_filesize=512M
6. max_file_uploads=20

Any ideas with configs or video size/length limits mattering this case would be much appreciated!

Comment: The video I am using has the specs of:
Width: 1920px, Heigth: 1080px, FPS: 25, Bit rate: 128kbps, Length: 28s, Size: 12,7 Mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a 'feature' with Chrome browser itself. Firefox and Canary are working better with multiple videos.